# How to export html table to excel with fit all column on one page setting

Tags: javascript, excel, html-table, export

i want to export my html table to excel worksheet with fit all column on one page setting, this is my code but it's not working, please help! Thanks you so much!

```
                        emplate += '<style><!--table {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";}  @page {mso-header-data:"&";  mso-footer-data:"&P/&N";' +

                                      ' margin:.31in 0in .31in 0in;  mso-header-margin:0in;  mso-footer-margin:0in;  mso-page-orientation:landscape; mso-page-scale: .1 .0}  --></style>';
                        template += '<xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>Sheet1</x:Name>';

                        template += '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:FitColumns/><x:Selected/><x:FreezePanes/><x:FrozenNoSplit/><x:SplitHorizontal>' + freezeTopRowNumber + '</x:SplitHorizontal><x:TopRowBottomPane>' + freezeTopRowNumber + '</x:TopRowBottomPane>';
                        template += '<x:Print><x:ValidPrinterInfo/><x:PaperSizeIndex>9</x:PaperSizeIndex><x:HorizontalResolution>600</x:HorizontalResolution><x:VerticalResolution>600</x:VerticalResolution></x:Print>';

                        template += '<x:ActivePane>2</x:ActivePane><x:Panes><x:Pane><x:Number>3</x:Number></x:Pane><x:Pane><x:Number>2</x:Number></x:Pane></x:Panes>';
                        template += '<x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents><x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects><x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios>';
                        template += '<x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook>';
                        template += '<x:ExcelName><x:Name>Print_Titles</x:Name><x:SheetIndex>1</x:SheetIndex><x:Formula>=Sheet1!$6:$6</x:Formula></x:ExcelName></xml><![endif]--></head>';
                        template += '<body style="text-align:center"><center>{table}</center></body></html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following tag successfully `mso-fit-text-to-shape:true` in excel which will shrink the print out to a single page.

some references here: [Export to Excel Page Orientation](https://forums.asp.net/t/1210717.aspx?Export+to+Excel+Page+Orientation) & [mso-fit-shape-to-text](https://documentation.help/DHTML-zh/box_mso-fit-shape-to-text.html)